# ActionMailer wrong number of arguments error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a rails app that allows you to request an invite to sign up. Upon request I save your email and send you an email saying thanks 'you have requested to join in'. For some reason the line `UserMailer.request(@request).deliver` gives me this error ArgumentError in RequestsController#create -- wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)

Any ideas?

**requests controller**

```
class RequestsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @request = Request.new
  end

  def create
    @request = Request.new(params[:request])
    if @request.valid?
      if User.find_by_email(@request.email) || Invitation.find_by_email(@request.email)
        redirect_to log_in_path, notice: "Email already in use"
      elsif @request.save
        @request.save
        redirect_to root_url, :notice => "Request sent."
        UserMailer.request(@request).deliver
      end
    else
        render "new"
    end
  end
end
```

**request.html.haml**

```
You have requested to join in
```

**mailers/user_mailer.rb**

```
class UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  def request(request)
    @request = request
    mail(:to => request.email, :subject => "Requested an invite", :from => 'alain@lootfly.com')
  end
end
```

Comment: It looks fine, are you running this in production mode? Do you need to restart the server? Can you call the line from console and see what it says?

Comment: I ran it from console and got the same error. And i'm not sure if i'm in production or development

Comment: i think it's a glitch i think there is actually nothing wrong

Comment: Sounds like a glitch, but I did notice that you are saving @request twice, take the second one out. And then maybe try putting the "UserMailer.request(@request).deliver" before the redirect_to, it should not make a difference but doesn't hurt to try, I have seen weirder things.

Comment: tried it @tronmcp still nothing

Comment: Not good! I have had some obscure problems similar to this mixing Ruby 1.8.7 and Ruby 1.9 with Rails 2.x and 3.x... I'm not sure what you are running and not saying this will help, just a thought... Good luck, wish I had more insight to help you out.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think `request` is a reserved word. Try change to `request_mail` and see whether it works.

Answer (score 3):

I would also guess that you can't name a model Request or have an instance variable in your controller named @request